# Dice simulation in java

Tags: java, simulation, dice

I'm trying to simulate rolling a die 100 times, and printing the results of how many 1/2/3/4/5/6 i landed. Here's my code thus far: I'm trying to use a while loop for my assignment, and i need to use (Math.random( )*6 + 1) to generate numbers.

```
public class RollingDice {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int count = 0; // number of times die was rolled
        int count1s = 0; // number of times 1 was rolled
        int count2s = 0; // number of times 2 was rolled
        int count3s = 0;
        int count4s = 0;
        int count5s = 0;
        int count6s = 0;

        while (count < 100) {
            count1s = (int) (Math.random( )*6 + 1);
            count2s = (int) (Math.random( )*6 + 1);
            count3s = (int) (Math.random( )*6 + 1);
            count4s = (int) (Math.random( )*6 + 1);
            count5s = (int) (Math.random( )*6 + 1);
            count6s = (int) (Math.random( )*6 + 1);

            count++;

    }
        System.out.println("Number of times the die was rolled: "+ count);
        System.out.println("Number of times 1 was rolled: " + count1s);
        System.out.println("Number of times 2 was rolled: " + count2s);
        System.out.println("Number of times 3 was rolled: " + count3s);
        System.out.println("Number of times 4 was rolled: " + count4s);
        System.out.println("Number of times 5 was rolled: " + count5s);
        System.out.println("Number of times 6 was rolled: " + count6s);

    }
}
```

My code currently prints:

```
Number of times the die was rolled: 100
Number of times 1 was rolled: 3
Number of times 2 was rolled: 1
Number of times 3 was rolled: 5
Number of times 4 was rolled: 2
Number of times 5 was rolled: 4
Number of times 6 was rolled: 4
```

As you can see, its rolling 100 times, but its only saving the results of 1 roll, not 100, How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your logic is incorrect.

Inside `while` loop, you assigned appearance time of each roll with value of dice.
=> Counter of each always < 7.

Also, each time your call `Math.random()` will give you new value => Should call it once each roll.

In this case, use `switch - case` statement will be correct.

```
  while (count < 100) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random( )*6 + 1);
        switch(num)  {
            case 1: 
                count1s++;
                break;
            case 2:
                count2s++;
                break;
            case 3: 
                count3s++;
                break;
            case 4: 
                count4s++;
                break;
            case 5:
                count5s++;
                break;
            case 6: 
                count6s++;
                break;
        }
        count++;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot all about switch statements

Answer (score 3):

On each iteration of your while loop, you are reassigning the value of `count1s`, `count2s`, and the others. Instead what you should do is you should "roll the dice" and then see what value it is, and increment the proper variable.

```
while (count < 100) {
    int diceRoll = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    if (diceRoll == 1) 
        count1s++;
    else if (diceRoll == 2)
        count2s++;
    // ... you get the idea

    count++;
}
```

And as a fun sidenote, using Java 8 there is a significantly easier, and more cool way to do this.

```
        Stream.generate(() -> (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1))
             .limit(100L)
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num -> num, 
                 Collectors.counting()))
             .forEach((num, count) -> System.out.println("number of times " + num + " was rolled: " + count));
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Was driving me insane. Man that was simple

Comment: Nice solution on Java 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration you are replacing the previous roll's data.You can rewrite the logic as

```
// initialization
while(count < 100){
   int currentRoll = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
   if(currentRoll == 1)
      count1s++;
  // Same logic for all occurances
}
```